# What is the keyboard shortcut to detach a developer console in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mac

I can toggle the developer console using the key `Command-I` on firefox, as you can see in the screenshot below

[image]

How can I easily detach the developer console using keyboard shortcut from the browser? I want to avoid resizing the browser everytime just to make the icon 'show in seperate window' in the toolbar visible.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you undock it it stays undocked for that website. 
You could try firebug addon for firefox as an alternative. Does basically the same thing but might have the shortcut you're looking for.

Comment: Firebug can be toggled by `F12`. (Oops - might not be true on Mac)